# Error: Method Not Allowed (POST): "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to make register possible on the homepage, so I don't have a seperate URL to handle registration. I'm trying to send the form through `get_context_data`, however it's not working. Here's my code:

**forms.py**

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = [
            'username',
            'password',
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
class BoxesView(ListView):
    template_name = 'polls.html'

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super(BoxesView, self).get_context_data()

        # login
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserRegistrationForm(self.request.POST or None)
            context['form'] = form
            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data['username']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
                user.save()
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                print(form.errors) #doesn't print anything
                print(form.non_field_errors()) #doesn't print anything
                print('Errors') #doesn't print anything
        else:
            form = UserRegistrationForm()
            context['form'] = form

    return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        pass
```

**base.html**

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="registerBox">
        {{ form.username }}
        {{ form.password }}
        <input type="submit" value="register"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

So when I submit the form it gives this error: `Method Not Allowed (POST): "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 0`

And it isn't creating a new User. Any idea what the problem is?

EDIT: Tried FormMixin, got this error: `The view app.views.BoxesView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

```
class BoxesView(ListView):
    template_name = 'polls.html'   
    form_class = UserRegistrationForm 

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
            user.save()
            return redirect('/')

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super(BoxesView, self).get_context_data()
        context['form'] = self.get_form()


        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        pass
```

Comment: `user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)` take inside if. Bu this is not the problem I think. Are you sure your url is fine?

Comment: Just fixed indentation. Well the thing is this is my homepage - so there is no seperate URL for registration. So registration is accessed via javascript  (onclick) from the homepage. Any idea if this is affecting it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see the issue fix the indentation, your if statement should be inside the get_context_data function not outside ;)

Comment: Just fixed the indentation, but still not working. Same Error: Method Not Allowed (POST): “POST / HTTP/1.1” 405 0

Comment: Instead of using get_context_data use the post method, take a look at this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views

Comment: You are also missing the action="" ? you need to specify the URL where you want to post to. Take a look at your urls.py and the URL you added for your view will have to be the one used in the action.

Comment: I used the post() method and it removed the error, but didn't create a new User. I posted my code in my edit. Also why do I need an `action` value? I've seen many tutorials without it.

Comment: Add a print statement right below form.is_valid() and check if is going inside the if statement, if is not then is an issue with your Form.

Comment: I added a print statement below `form.is_valid()` (not inside) and it successfully printed. This was using the code in my new edit, could you check it out? I used FormMixin and post() but got this error: `The view app.views.BoxesView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `post()` method and `FormMixin` to your CBV like this:

```
class BoxesView(FormMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'polls.html'
    form_class = UserRegistrationForm
    # ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            # ...
        else:
            # ...
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'data': some_data})
```

Comment: I've tried that already as well. I didn't get any errors but it didn't create a new User.

Comment: And you're sure you form data were valid? because 'it did not create a new User' might be caused by something else!

Comment: `form.is_valid()` returned False, so yes the data may not of been valid but i'm not sure why. I posted the code in my edit.

Comment: Try with `FormMixin` and `form_class` attribute.

Comment: Tried it and got `The view app.views.BoxesView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` error. Could you look at my edit where I show the code?